# Make all URLs absolute in a context with both absolute and relative URLs

Tags: python, url

I'm working on a web scraping system, and I'm trying to deal with making all URLs absolute.

Basically, is there a *proper* way to make a URL absolute?

`urllib.parse.urljoin` can not do this.

```
>>> urllib.parse.urljoin('http://www.google.com', 'www.bing.com')
'http://www.google.com/www.bing.com'
```

so blindly flattening all links with `urllib.parse.urljoin()` is not viable. 
Tt does work in cases where the absolute URL has a full scheme:

```
>>> urllib.parse.urljoin('http://www.google.com', 'http://www.bing.com/')
'http://www.bing.com/'
```

This seems like the sort of thing that should be in the `urllib.parse` module, or somewhere similar. I can roll my own canonizer by futzing with the output of `urllib.parse.urlsplit()` to decide if I need to conditionally `urljoin()` a url onto the url root, but that seems crude.

Comment: If a link only reads "www.bing.com" then `urllib.parse.urljoin()` is absolutely doing the correct thing with regards to how a browser would do it. Unless you expect the function to be psychic.

Comment: What is wrong with `http://www.google.com/www.bing.com`? Its a perfectly valid URL.

Answer (score 0):

Well in most cases, the relative URL does not have a "www." in it. So you can run a check on the second URL and then join the urls

```
def joinURLs(main,relative):
    if 'www.' in relative:
        return relative
    return urllib.parse.urljoin(main,relative)
```

Comment: Just returning `relative` won't turn it into a proper URL.